# Have YouTube notify a URL when a video is published?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently in the process of building a site, and one of the features that I want is to allow users who use YouTube to be able to have their videos automatically added to their feeds without them having to do anything.

I know that you can use YouTube's Data API to get a specific users videos, but I don't want to keep relying on that to check if a user has uploaded a new video, as it would become a burden, especially after more and more users register, as I'd have to check every 10 minutes or so for each account, and that adds up.

Therefore, **I was wondering if YouTube had a feature in their API that would allow YouTube to notify a specific URL on my site when a user has published a video to YouTube.** I've seen sites use YouTube to authenticate certain permissions, but I'm not sure if this is one, or what to specifically search.

Comment: It's possible with push notifications: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the YouTube Data API v2 *should* support PubSubHubbub notifications, which is basically what you describe: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/10/pubsubhubbub-for-youtube-activities.html

That *should* refers to the fact that PubSubHubbub within the YouTube API has a somewhat checkered history, as you might be able to tell from reading the **Updates** added to that blog post. I was actually just debugging some PubSubHubbub issues with the engineering team today, and while updates don't appear to be pushed out right now, a change going live early next week should hopefully resolve that.

An alternative approach is to use the [Simple Update Protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_sup), but that requires some degree of polling.

The YouTube API engineering team is aware of the need to provide a stable, reliable means of subscribing to push updates in the new v3 of the API, but we don't have anything to announce yet.